# Why is Bitcoin Core using LevelDB instead of Redis or SQLite?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, utxo, database, leveldb

Why did Core move from `BDB` to `LevelDB`? Why don't they use `SQLite` or move to `Redis` now? Is there a technical reason for this choice?

Comment: The bdb->leveldb change was made to increase speed while validating blocks and during initial block download. Also, doesn't redis require that you load your entire dataset into memory? Pretty painful for a 60GB blockchain.

Comment: but redis uses LZF light data compressor , this won't help to reduce the data volume in memory? and i thought leveldb was chosen because it supports high caching data.

Comment: LevelDB also supports compression. We explicitly disable it in Bitcoin Core because it does not help (almost all the data in the database consists of uncompressible cryptographic material anyway: hashes, keys, signatures).

Comment: @Nick We wouldn't store the entire blockchain in the database anyway.

Comment: as i know we store only the blocks and the state of validation < blockchain

Comment: Not even the blocks. Those are stored on disk, but not in a database. The only data of significance in the database is the UTXO set.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Redis and LevelDB solve very different problems. We tried using SQLite and its performance was abysmal.

Bitcoin Core needs a database to store the set of unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs). This means we need fast simple reads, and fast batches of random updates.

We don't need a server/client architecture, as we can't have multiple applications accessing the database at once anyway: inconsistencies in the database would lead to forking risks (every node in the network needs to make exactly the same judgement about what is valid and invalid).

Comment: Has LMDB been considered?

Comment: @Pieter Wuille Do you consider that moving from BDB to LevelDB was a correct decision? Or LevelDB is causing major problems that didn't happened with BDB? (ex: file corruption, bugs ...)